# Editar arquivo txt remotamente

Tags: php, html, front-end

Eu gostaria de fazer uma página em HTML, e usar uma página PHP para editar o texto da página HTML (como se fosse um `Frontend`).

Existe algum código PHP para isso?

No meu exemplo a página HTML à ser editada é a [`buysingle.html`](http://hugovales.esy.es/buysingle.html)

(No caso, eu vou usar o conteúdo da página `buysingle.html` para carregar dentro de uma `modal` que eu criei para comprar a música.)

Eu queria uma página PHP que tivesse o código da página HTML sempre dentro de uma caixa de texto, e que eu pudesse editar e salvar.

Obrigado, desde já.

Código do arquivo de texto à ser editado:

```
    <div id="albumtrack1">
    <a style="color:lightgrey; text-decoration: none; -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;"><br>
            Buy "I Don't Wanna Your Love"
          </a><br>
       <p style="color:grey; text-decoration: none; -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;">You can not end this purchase. Music was not yet released.</p>
</div>
<div id="albumtrack2">
    <a style="color:lightgrey; text-decoration: none; -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;"><br>
            Buy "Pure"
          </a><br>
<p style="color:grey; text-decoration: none; -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;">You can not end this purchase. Music was not yet released.</p>
</div>
<div id="albumtrack3">
    <a style="color:lightgrey; text-decoration: none; -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;"><br>
            Buy "Sleep Close to Me"
          </a><br>
<p style="color:grey; text-decoration: none; -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;">You can not end this purchase. Music was not yet released.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Por favor nos mostre o que você já tentou e ou pelo menos o código da página html.

Comment: Eu Ainda não consegui tentar nada, por que eu procurei e não achei algum código que pudesse fazer isso.

Comment: Editei a Pergunta e Inseri o Código da Página HTML á ser editada pelo PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso criarei um arquivo: `editar.php`

```
<?php
  $pagina = "buysingle.html";
  if(isset($_POST)){
    if($_POST["conteudo"]){
      $fopen = fopen($pagina,"w+");
      fwrite($fopen,$_POST["conteudo"]);
      fclose($fopen);
    }
  }
?>
<h1>Editar a pagina: <?= $pagina; ?></h1>
<form method="post">
  <textarea name="conteudo"><?= file_get_contents($pagina); ?></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Salvar"/>
</form>
```

## Explicando:

1. Define uma variável para guardar o nome do arquivo, chamado de `$pagina`.
2. Cria um formulário para exibir o conteúdo atual, para então o usuário editar.
3. Se houve uma requisição no método `POST` (se o usuário clicou em salvar!) ele então verifica se existe "conteúdo" do `POST`, se sim, ele então ele seleciona o nosso arquivo (fopen) no modo para leitura e escrita (a+) e logo em seguida escreve neste arquivo tudo que o usuário digitou no "conteúdo" do `POST`, logo em seguida, fecha o arquivo!

## Para saber mais sobre manipulação de arquivo com php, recomendo: http://www.samuelcorradi.com.br/manipulando_arquivos_php.html

Comment: Eu testei o código, mas oque ele faz é "Adicionar".

Comment: O Que eu quero é algo que edite mesmo o código.

Comment: Tens razão, @HugoMarcelo viajei, ao invés de a+ coloque w+.

Comment: Eu devo substituir w+ por a+ e está resolvido?

Comment: Eu substituí "w+" por "r+". É Esse Resultado que eu quero. Seu Código me ajudou muitíssimo! Obrigado :)

Comment: A de nada, e desculpa pelos erros, eu não cheguei a testar uhsah....